# The sum of length of two sub-lists does not equal the length of the original list

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an Excel file with the following columns: `email_address, first_name, last_name, took_action`, the first three columns have related data (belongs to one person), and the fourth column has a list of names of people who took action. I want to extract the names of people who did not take action. This is my code:

```
import openpyxl

csv_file = r'.\list.xlsx'
dataframe = openpyxl.load_workbook(csv_file)
dataframe_reader = dataframe.active

emails = []
first_names = []
last_names = []
took_action = []
neutral = []

for row in range(2, dataframe_reader.max_row+1):
  emails.append(dataframe_reader.cell(row = row, column = 1).value)
  first_names.append(dataframe_reader.cell(row = row, column = 2).value)
  last_names.append(dataframe_reader.cell(row = row, column = 3).value)
  if dataframe_reader.cell(row = row, column = 4).value != None:
    took_action.append(dataframe_reader.cell(row = row, column = 4).value)

first_names_set = set(first_names)
took_action_set = set(took_action)

for name in first_names_set:
  if name not in took_action_set:
    neutral.append(name)

print(f'neutral + took action = {len(neutral) + len(took_action_set)}')
print(f'first_names_set len = {len(first_names_set)}')
```

I expect the code to give my the following output:

```
neutral + took action = 100
first_names_set len = 100
```

But I am getting the following output instead:

```
neutral + took action = 101
first_names_set len = 100
```

How come the sum of the two sub-lists is more than the length of the original list?

Comment: Remember that a `set` won't contain duplicates. So `len(first_names_set)` is not the length of the original list, but the number of unique elements in it. You may want to check the result with `len(first_names)` and `len(took_action)`.

Comment: If you need further insight, you will need to show some example data, it's not very obvious what's going on. For example if column 4 (took action) really contains the same kind of content as column 2 (first names), just with gaps.

Comment: @tevemadar I tried what you mentioned, but still, same result. Unfortunately, I cannot provide some example data since they are PIIs.

Comment: You could hardcode some fake data for testing. `emails` and `last_names` are not used anyway, so just produce some lists for the other two with 5-10 elements, like `first_names=["A","B","C","C","D"]` and `took_action=[None,?,?,?,?]` (I don't know what it contains when it's not `None`). With such small amount of data you can then see what `neutral` actually becomes, not just its length.

Comment: As you state `neutral + took action` should be equal to or less than the total number of entries being processed. But as @tevemadar states your asking us to guess. You need to debug, check the values, print out your lists. Have you checked which variable is returning the incorrect value, `neutral` or `took_action_set`?

Comment: @tevemadar Thank you for the enlightening comment, I hardcoded the values and removed half of the took_action list (binary search) and tested, did that few times until I found the error, somehow, one of the names was manipulated (not sure how and why), but this caused the issue. Now it works fine. I appreciate your time.